# Capturar a localização atual do usuario em um intervalo de tempo e envia-la para o servidor

Tags: android

Fala galera.

Então, preciso que meu app envie a localização do usuário para meu servidor remoto a cada x minutos. Gostaria de saber qual seria o melhor workflow para que isso aconteça da maneira correta. Penso que o caminho é usando Services e AlarmManager mas nunca implementei algo do tipo e estou em duvida sobre o workflow correto a seguir. Outro ponto importante é a necessidade da localização do usuario ser enviada para o servidor remoto mesmo que o app esteja não esteja em execução.

Comment: De quanto em quanto tempo pretende enviar esta informação?

Answer (score 0):

Tu vai usar um `AlarmManager` que inicia um `Service` a cada X seg, o tempo que desejar.

O `Service` deve incluir uma classe que implementa um `location listener`.

E você simplesmente obtém a localizaçao dentro de uma **activity** do **Service** e envia para o servidor usando a `AsyncTask`.

Da uma olhada nesse link que pode te ajudar: [link](http://ukgupta.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/acquiring-gps-location-fix.html#comment-form)